# Failed to get absolute path to installed module

Tags: git, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm with a problem that I believe that is something related to my package.json or the version of the cordova platform.

When I try to run an `ionic state restore` it returns the following output:

```
Attempting to restore your Ionic application from package.json

Restoring Platforms

cordova platform add ios
cordova platform add android

Restore platforms is complete

Restoring Plugins

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-console
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen
cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-compat
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media
cordova plugin add https://github.com/AubreyHewes/cordova-background-audio.git
Caught exception:
 undefined

Mind letting us know? https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues
```

And when I try to run the command that failed (`cordova plugin add https://github.com/AubreyHewes/cordova-background-audio.git`), it returns the following error:

```
Error: Failed to fetch plugin git+https://github.com/AubreyHewes/cordova-background-audio.git via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Failed to get absolute path to installed module
```

I don't understand why it says that is a connection problem, because my internet connection is working just fine. Also the URL of the plugin is right too.

My environment info:

```
Cordova CLI: 7.0.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0
ios-sim version: 5.0.10
OS: OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v7.0.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.1 Build version 8B62
```

I'm pulling my hairs out for this problem. Do you have a clue of what can be causing this?

My package.json content:

```
{
  "name": "paranaiba-app",
  "version": "1.1.1",
  "description": "paranaiba-app: An Ionic project",
  "dependencies": {
    "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
    "cordova-ios": "^4.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "~1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "~1.0.6",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "~1.1.5",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "~4.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-media": "~2.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-music-controls": "git+https://github.com/homerours/cordova-music-controls-plugin.git",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "~1.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "~4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "~2.2.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "~1.3.2",
    "gulp": "^3.5.6",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "~2.2.1",
    "nl.kingsquare.cordova.background-audio": "git+https://github.com/AubreyHewes/cordova-background-audio.git",
    "phonegap-plugin-push": "~1.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.3.3",
    "gulp-util": "^2.2.14",
    "shelljs": "^0.3.0"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information",
    "cordova-plugin-file",
    "cordova-plugin-compat",
    "cordova-plugin-media",
    {
      "locator": "https://github.com/AubreyHewes/cordova-background-audio.git",
      "id": "nl.kingsquare.cordova.background-audio"
    },
    {
      "locator": "https://github.com/homerours/cordova-music-controls-plugin",
      "id": "cordova-plugin-music-controls"
    }
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    {
      "platform": "ios",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "ios"
    },
    {
      "platform": "android",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "android"
    }
  ],
  "cordova": {
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
    ],
    "plugins": {
      "phonegap-plugin-push": {
        "SENDER_ID": "XXXX"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-console": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-compat": {},
      "cordova-plugin-media": {},
      "nl.kingsquare.cordova.background-audio": {},
      "cordova-plugin-music-controls": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you able to add this plugin on the pure cordova app for checking whether this cordova's problem or your app? There were some changes in fetch logic in cordova-7.0, probably it affects your app.

Comment: @Bob tried it right now, and worked just fine: `Saved plugin info for "nl.kingsquare.cordova.background-audio" to config.xml`. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Try to remove this plugin from node_modules manually in your ionic app and install this plugin again,

Comment: Cordova finds difference between files before and after installation plugin in node_modules, if there is no difference  and  git repoName is different than moduleID it can lead to error you recieve.

Comment: @Bob thank you very much, worked just fine removing the plugin from `node_modules/` and reinstalling it.

Comment: my pleasure, but anyway, it's bug in cordova-7.0, I'll make contribution to fix it :)

Comment: @Bob even thought it reinstalled, when I try to run the `ionic state restore` it keeps returning error when restoring this plugin: `Caught exception:
 undefined` (same error on the code quote on the problem description above). Do you have an idea of what may be causing this?

Comment: try to remove plugin from node_modules and run `ionic state resore`

Comment: @Bob Worked just fine. But I had to delete from `node_modules` all plugins that use git to restore. Thanks.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I got the same error message when adding a local plugin: `Error: Failed to get absolute path to installed module`.

Using the option `--nofetch` (cordova@7.0.1) fixed it:

`cordova plugin add ../my-plugin --nofetch`

According to https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli/blob/master/RELEASENOTES.md :
Use `--nofetch` flag to fetch platforms and plugins using old fetching logic.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The link in the accepted answer even mentions this flag.

Comment: Does the `--nofetch` flag save to `package.json` - it doesn't appear to for me, and as a result, running `cordova prepare` on a fresh clone produces the same error.

Comment: @keldar have you got it working with cordova prepare? I have got the same error message when adding a local plugin.

Comment: `--nofetch` option is removed in Cordova 8.0.0: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13055

Comment: so do we have an alternative now that --nofetch is gone?

Comment: I guess downgradd to 7.0.1 :(

Answer (score 13):

Edit: This answer is outdated. Please use the [answer of uutrecht](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44020193/4303873) instead.

---

I had the same problem right now. I fixed it by downgrading cordova from v7.0.0 to v6.5.0

`npm i -g cordova@6.5.0`

They changed the way how they fetch the plugins. https://cordova.apache.org/news/2017/05/04/cordova-7.html

Comment: I think I'll do that. Every time I want to restore the state of the project I have to delete all node_modules manually. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: how can I downgrade the cordova version ?

Comment: Look at the command I mentioned `sudo npm i -g cordova@X.X.X`
Replace `X.X.X` with the version you'd like to use.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup about the @uutrecht answer

Comment: This link was probably the most helpful for me. I'm going to try ```cordova config set fetch false``` and hope that it'll set it back to the pre version 7 behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the plugin, you installed from local, from the config.xml, the package.json and the package-lock.json.

Then try again.
I work for most of cases.

```
{
    "name": "io.cordova.hellocordova",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "displayName": "HelloCordova",
    "cordova": {
        "platforms": [
            "android"
        ],
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "com-example-plugin": {}
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
        "cordova-plugin-template": "file:../cordova-testplugin",  // <-- remove this line
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.2"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`--nofetch` option has been removed in Cordova version 8.0.0: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13055

If you have already installed Cordova 8.x.x then you can downgrade it to version 7.1.0 and then use the `--nofetch` option.

Run the following command to downgrade Cordova to 7.1.0:

```
npm install -g cordova@7.1.0
```

If the above command doesn't work, then try uninstalling cordova at first and then install cordova version 7.1.0:

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm install -g cordova@7.1.0
```

Then, check the Cordova version to confirm if it's downgraded or not:

```
cordova --version
```

Comment: It is `--nofetch `

Comment: Thanks @VarunGarg for the correction. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This answer applies to: Cordova 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)

In my case, it had to do with `git+https://...` part of the url, listed in `package.json` under dependencies. Changing it to `https://...` did the trick.

In the cordova src they use a module `cordova-fetch`. In the function `getPath` the error is thrown. It might call `searchDirForTarget` which in turn calls module `is-url`. The target, e.g. the url, gets validated here and `git+https://...` yields invalid because it does not match `/^(?:\w+:)?\/\/(\S+)$/`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it running the folowing command (using cordova v 8.1.2):

`ionic cordova plugin rm PLUGIN_NAME && ionic cordova plugin add PLUGIN_NAME`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the id of plugin's package.json different with git repo name

for example:
  id of package.json => com.abc.cde
  the git url must be https://github.com/{username}/com.abc.cde.git